# Bash sed awk, format CPU/Mem info from /proc/cpuinfo and /proc/meminfo

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, cpu

The problem that I'm trying to solve is to produce portable output that I can display on all of the servers in our environment to show basic info at login using generic information on all CentOS / Red Hat systems. I would like to pluck info from `/proc/cpuinfo` and `/proc/meminfo` (or `free -m -h`); "why not just '`yum install some-great-tool`'?" is not ideal as all of this information is freely available to us right in `/proc`. I know that this sort of thing can often be a very simple trick for sed/awk experts (I don't know how to approach this
with my limited sed/awk knowledge).

I would like to extract something like the following on a single line:

```
<model name>, <cpu MHz> MHz, <cpu cores> cores, <detect "vmx" (Intel-VT) or "svm" (AMD-V support)>
```

e.g. with the below output, this would look like (with "1300.000" rounded to "1300")

```
"AMD Athlon(tm) II Neo N36L Dual-Core Processor, 1300 MHz, 2 cores, VMX-Virtualization" (or "SVM-Virtualization" or "No Virtualization")
```

I would like to also combine this info with that of `/proc/meminfo` or `free -mh`, so:

```
"AMD Athlon(tm) II Neo N36L Dual-Core Processor, 1300 MHz, 2 cores, 4.7 GB Memory (1.8 GB Free), SVM-Virtualization"
```

I have spent some time searching for methods, but without luck, and maybe this is an interesting generic problem as involves taking the format of tables that a lot of info is held in and extracting as required so has some generic application.

`$ free -m -h`

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          4.5Gi       1.2Gi       1.8Gi        77Mi       1.6Gi       3.0Gi
Swap:         4.8Gi          0B       4.8Gi
```

`$ cat /proc/cpuinfo`

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : AuthenticAMD
cpu family      : 16
model           : 6
model name      : AMD Athlon(tm) II Neo N36L Dual-Core Processor
stepping        : 3
microcode       : 0x10000c8
cpu MHz         : 1300.000
cache size      : 1024 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 2
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 5
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm 3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid pni monitor cx16 popcnt lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt nodeid_msr hw_pstate vmmcall npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save
bugs            : tlb_mmatch apic_c1e fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs null_seg amd_e400 spectre_v1 spectre_v2
bogomips        : 2595.59
TLB size        : 1024 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm stc 100mhzsteps hwpstate
```

`$ cat /proc/meminfo`

```
MemTotal:        4771304 kB
MemFree:         1862372 kB
MemAvailable:    3195768 kB
Buffers:            2628 kB
Cached:          1542788 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          1534572 kB
Inactive:         909316 kB
Active(anon):     917792 kB
Inactive(anon):    62468 kB
Active(file):     616780 kB
Inactive(file):   846848 kB
Unevictable:        8384 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       5070844 kB
SwapFree:        5070844 kB
Dirty:                20 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        881304 kB
Mapped:           395420 kB
Shmem:             79776 kB
KReclaimable:     152892 kB
Slab:             295508 kB
SReclaimable:     152892 kB
SUnreclaim:       142616 kB
KernelStack:        9328 kB
PageTables:        45156 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     7456496 kB
Committed_AS:    5260708 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:             2864 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:    417792 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:      314944 kB
DirectMap2M:     4796416 kB
DirectMap1G:           0 kB
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't know it did that so I've unchecked the 'accepted' flag for now. Could you please show me your full answer. I love to see different techniques, always really useful/interesting! And is collecting the SVM / VMX info easily doable?

Comment: Someone has aggressively closed it, and I see they've put "-2" flags on it too. I really don't get it. I find your and Raman's answers fascinating, and I've already learned tons from both. Is my question considered beneath their contempt or something? I don't get why they want to crush this kind of creativity and interesting discussion...

"Closed. This question needs details or clarity. It is not currently accepting answers. Add details and clarify the problem you’re solving. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question or post a new one.
Closed 1 hour ago."

Comment: I guess your ultimate "objective" with the sample wasn't clear enuf... Just open a new thread with the clearER definition (with sample) of what you're after so that we know what we're striving for.

Comment: Well, you and Raman could understand it easily enough. I just don't get the aggressive downvoting and censoring/closing for an interesting topic. I can't close this as Raman gave a great answer, and on reading it above, it's absolutely clear what I am asking (is it possible to make it more clear?) so it just looks like it was closed for no reason. Hopefully someone with 3000+ privilege can open it again, as would be great to see what other techniques people might use.

Comment: interesting... now most of **my** comments are gone with the alternate solution. oh well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using /proc/cpuinfo and free -mh along with awk, search for the strings required, using : as the field delimited, set variables accordingly, splitting the output of free -mh further into an array called arr based on " " as the delimiter. At the end, print the data in the required format using the variables created.

When searching for lines beginning with flag, we search for strings svn or vmx using awk's match function. A match will signified by the RSTART variable not being 0 and so we check this to find the type of virtualisatiion being utilised. As we have set virt to No Virtualisation at the beginning, no matches will print No Virtualisation.

```
  awk -F: '/^model name/ { 
                         mod=$2 
                        } 
         /^cpu MHz/    { 
                         mhz=$2 
                        } 
         /^cpu core/ {
                         core=$2
                     } 
         /^flags/ { 
                         virt="No Virtualisation";
                         match($0,"svm");
                         if (RSTART!=0) 
                                       { 
                                         virt="SVM-Virtualisation" 
                                       };
                         match($0,"vmx");
                         if (RSTART!=0) { 
                                         virt="VMX-Virtualisation" 
                                        } 
                  }
         /^Mem:/ {
                         split($2,arr," ");
                         tot=arr[1];
                         free=arr[2]
                  } 
         END { 
                         printf "%s %dMHz %s core(s) %s %sB Memory (%sB Free)\n",mod,mhz,core,virt,tot,free 
             }' /proc/cpuinfo <(free -mh)
```

One liner:

```
awk -F: '/^model name/ { mod=$2 } /^cpu MHz/ { mhz=$2 } /^cpu core/ {core=$2} /^flags/ { virt="No Virtualisation";match($0,"svm");if (RSTART!=0) { virt="SVM-Virtualisation" };match($0,"vmx");if (RSTART!=0) { virt="VMX-Virtualisation" } } /^Mem:/ {split($2,arr," ");tot=arr[1];free=arr[2]} END { printf "%s %dMHz %s core(s) %s %sB Memory (%sB Free)\n",mod,mhz,core,virt,tot,free }' /proc/cpuinfo <(free -mh)
```

Comment: That is absolutely crazy, thanks so much @Raman ! Really fascinating. The SVM / VMX would be another thing, but this is incredible... I've just been looking at it for 15 minutes in awe. Amazing. :) I understand the elements of what you are doing here (it's completely clear what is going on). I can really use this for a lot of situations I think ... I'll be looking at this a lot I think! :)

Comment: Changed the split to `": "` instead of `:` idea to remove those leading/trailing spaces and added some commas to separate the output. ok so now I have to pick out the line with svm in it and somehow just get a yes/no answer for the virtualization flag. Pretty amazing thanks, looks great as output from `.bashrc` :)
`awk -F": " '/^model name/ { mod=$2 } /^cpu MHz/ { mhz=$2 } /^cpu core/ {core=$2} /^Mem:/ {split($2,arr," ");tot=arr[1];free=arr[2]} END { printf "%s, %dMHz, %s core(s), %sB Memory (%sB Free)\n",mod,mhz,core,tot,free }' /proc/cpuinfo <(free -mh)`

Comment: No worries, I've added some logic for the type of virtualisation now also.